# Progress bar working but label text not ( already read the disccusion using c# but it confusing)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, progress-bar

Alright, every value i send is right, it's the matter how to show it. this is my progress bar and label text code. my progress bar are working smoothly but why my label text wont updated. This is my full upload code so please help me guys.

```
    Private Sub progressbar(size As Integer, uploaded As Integer)

    Dim i As Integer

    ProgressBar1.Minimum = 0
    ProgressBar1.Maximum = size

    For i = uploaded To size
        ProgressBar1.Value = i
        While ProgressBar1.Value < ProgressBar1.Maximum
            ProgressBar1.PerformStep()
            kondisi.Text = filesize(uploaded) & " " & "From" & " " & filesize(size)
            kondisi.Refresh()
        End While
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: i think your problem is, that you change the text of the control in a different thread. please use invoke to set the text in the correct thread. Please read here how to invoke a control: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: He's got the opposite problem.  That **tight loop** is running in the main UI thread which is why the Label isn't getting updated.  Move the "work" to a different thread and properly `Invoke()` the updates.

Comment: Also...what's the **point** of that code?  It's not reporting any **real** progress as far as I can tell...

Comment: um its kind of a larger code, cause im using it to count how much byte i already upload`progressbar(filesize, byteuploaded)`, can you give me a hint how to make a new thread, cause im still rookie in vb.net @Idle_Mind

Comment: @Idle_Mind i edited and give you my full upload code, can you help me, because many threading example cant give me a clear view about how to do it.

Comment: You need to follow a tutorial for a BackgroundWorker.  Never access gui controls in the background thread though, and only do the long timed work in the DoWork method.

Comment: okay i definitely try it, thanks @LarsTech